Can an MU-2 do a 360 degree roll?
If you wanted to do a Bob Hoover-like roll in an aircraft like the MU-2 that exclusively uses spoilers for roll control, I'm curious as to whether it can, and if so, what kind of control inputs would you use as the wings were near/at vertical?
I'm not a pilot, so I may be way off base here, but I can see the spoiler dumping lift off of one wing, causing that wing to drop, but once you approach wings vertical, then what?

You’d still have more lift from one wing than the other to produce the rolling moment, right?

Yes.
As long as the airplane maintains airspeed through the airmass it really doesn't matter what sort of control surface configuration is producing the rolling moment.  As long as the roll input is maintained, the aircraft will roll.  You can roll an airplane in a vertical climb or dive, with ailerons, spoilers, flaperons, etc., it really doesn't matter.

once you approach wings vertical, then what?

Presuming that the angle of attack remains positive, since the lift vector is not opposing gravity the aircraft will first begin to turn, and once past 90 deg AOB the lift vector will cause the nose to drop and the airplane to lose altitude.  Altitude loss can be compensated for my initiating roll with a nose up pitch, faster rate of roll, or wait until the you are upright again and pull back up to the horizon.

Now I get it. I was thinking that gravity caused the wing drop because of spoiler deployment, that's why I was having trouble understanding how the wing would start "up" when it was rolling from 90-270 degrees. It's all aerodynamics regardless of gravity. Thanks for the explanation!

@MichaelHall  That's for a postive G barrel roll.

@JohnK, what I described certainly applies to a barrel roll, but also to an "aileron" roll.  The question just asked about a 360 degree roll...

Yeah but if you're going actually into negative G, it's a whole new ballgame. The roll spoiler becomes a very skinny split flap.

that's why i worded my answer the way i did.

Depends on the type of roll.
If it's a barrel roll that maintains close to 1G "positive" throughout the roll (a barrel roll is more or less a loop stretched into a coil), the airplane doesn't know that the earth is revolving and the lift forces involved don't change (you remain in your seat with apparent gravity toward the floor), so around you go as normal.
An aileron roll, or slow roll, where you go into negative G flight with the wing generating lift up while upside down, it's another story. Once the wing is unloaded from positive G flight, the spoiler is now on the effective bottom (the high pressure side), acting more like a split flap. I would expect that at moderate extensions, the roll will continue when in negative G flight as the "split flap" spoiler is able to generate some lift in the direction of the roll (by simply deflecting air). With full spoiler (60 degrees), the rate could decrease as the "split flap" produces more drag than lift at high angles.  It's also possible that the chord of the roll spoilers being quite narrow, they do nothing but degrade lift in inverted flight same as upright flight, and you get a kind of control reversal.
I've never been able to find a description of how the MU-2 would perform in a slow roll or aileron roll, so it remains speculation.

I mean that's another way you could do a roll, but you can also do a fast aileron roll without pushing negative G.

You'll end up around zero G for much of it because you are going a bit ballistic to get it around quickly without going negative. WIth the wings unloaded, you are depending on the spoiler's ability to push the wing around as a deflector.

I've done lots of rolls in the spoiler equipped EA-6B, and yeah you might experience a little zero G, but the primary sensation is rotation.  I generally just left the stick neutral fore and aft.  Never tired a negative G roll, wish I still had access to one to try it!

So it sounds like the deflected spoiler acts like split flap, at least ta low AOAs. The MU-2's spoilers are actually cross connected like ailerons with a differential mixer. This means when you roll left, the left spoilers come out, and the right ones actually go down below the wing profile, about 1/3 the travel of the up spoiler. Mechanically, they are like ailerons, just skinny and moved forward ahead of the flaps.
